# Нет доступа к разделам

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Здраствуйте.Установил ubuntu примонтировал парочку разделов в /media но доступ к ним имеет только root.Как установить доступ для создвния и удаления файлов для всех пользователей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но я нашол  способ проще:Запускаем  nautilus с правами root командой gksudo nautilus открываем нужную папку, теперь в свойствах папки можна менять права пользователя,первым делом меняем владельца с root на админа или кого либо и права доступа какие пожылаете.подробнее об этом http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

В `/etc/fstab` для ваших точек монтирования установите

umask - user file creation mode mask, например, чтобы дать пользователям права чтения установите `umask=003` или `umask=0` чтобы всем и всё.

Так же попробуйте `dmask` и `fmask` чтобы отдельно задать права для директорий и файлов.

К вышеперечисленному, проверьте парава директорий в `/media`.